# Django 1.11 CreateView pass URL parameters

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am using Django 1.11 and I'm struggling to understand how I can pass URL parameters to a ModelForm using CreateView Class. I have 4 parameters in the URL (start_date, end_date, start_time, end_time) that i'm trying to pass to their relevant fields in the form. I'd really appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction to figuring out how to solve this!

The URL is created with the following function in my html file:

```
window.location.assign("/calendar/create?start_date="+start.format("YYYY-MM-DD")+"&end_date="+end.format("YYYY-MM-DD")+"start_time="+start.format("h:mm A")+"&end_time="+end.format("h:mm A"));
```

This opens from urls.py:

```
url(r'^calendar/create',views.CalendarCreate.as_view(),name='calendar_create'),
```

from views.py:

```
class CalendarCreate(CreateView):
    model = Event
    form_class = EventForm
```

from forms.py:

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

So far so good, my event_form.html opens with the form:
[image: form]

and an example URL generated is:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/calendar/create?start_date=2017-10-25&end_date=2017-10-25start_time=4:00%20PM&end_time=5:00%20PM

This is where I am stuck. From spending a number of days here in stackoverflow, googling, and trying numerous things I believe the solution involves `get_form_kwargs` or `get_context_data` or `form_valid` in `views.py` but it is possible I have just confused myself trying to work this out. Any help to get me on the right track will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't have to do anything, [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) should handle them automatically. What is the issue you are having?

Comment: Hi Selcuk, thanks for responding. The issue is I would like to pass the 4 URL parameters to the form, but the form is just loaded with no values in those fields. For example in the screenshot provided the start_date field would default to 25/10/2017 using the example URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class CalendarCreate(CreateView):
    model = Event
    form_class = EventForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = {}
        for x in self.request.GET:
            initial[x] = self.request.GET[x]
        print(initial)
        return initial
```

notice if `'start_date'` in `request.GET` you must have same field `'start_date'` in your `Event` model,and notice the time format is vaild.

Comment: Thank you Ykh so much! I have been stuck on this for days. i really appreciate your repsonse in helping me. Using your code the two date fields are now pre-populating correctly, however the time fields are not. Is this just a format issue I need to resolve? i notice the URL has %20 for the space between the time numbers and the AM/PM designator. For clarity if I manually complete the time field in the form I would select 4:00 PM using example from the URL time.

Comment: It was a format issue indeed. I changed my URL generation to: start_time="+start.format("kk:mm") and it now works. Thank you again!

Comment: it is my pleasure